# Error When trying to publish asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, godaddy-api

When I am trying to publish the asp.net website I am facing this error, However, the project build successfully in the local server.

```
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.

Connecting to ftp://e-jarkom.com/...
Transformed Web.config using C:\Users\Home\source\repos\BorrowThings\BorrowThings\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p C:\Users\Home\source\repos\BorrowThings\BorrowThings\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source -u C:\Users\Home\source\repos\BorrowThings\BorrowThings\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir 
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Deleting existing files...
Error deleting file 'cgi-bin'.  Cannot remove folder "cgi-bin".
Error deleting file 'error_docs'.  Cannot remove file "error_docs/bad_gateway.html". Error Code: 550.
Error deleting file 'logs'.  Cannot remove file "logs/iis/W3SVC396/u_ex200613.log". Error Code: 550.
Publish failed. Target ftp://e-jarkom.com/.
```

Comment: You could use [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) `Procmon` to see what is going on in system. I guess those files are locked by other process. Maybe your website is running and locks files.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're trying to delete files and don't have the proper permissions. When setting up that Publish profile, try unchecking Delete existing files.

Comment: this error did not have nothing to do with asp.net - its an ftp error - try to login manual to your ftp server and verify the directories that you have access